# CSS Styles for P tag to look like Header tags

Tags: html, css

I am trying add styles to certain texts under P tags to look similar to that of h1, h2 & h3 tags. I tried changing  the font-size  to 2em for h1 and 1.5em to h2. But at different location in the screen, accordingly to the content nearby, the size of these P tags  changes, and they nowhere look similar to h1 or h2 tags. My requirement strictly prohibits me to directly use header tags in those places. I need styles to make P tag look like Header tags in all screens.

**What I have done until now?**
I am currently adding a class  to these P tags, and I am adding styles to them with separate CSS file. my CSS Code:

```
p.smallText {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
p.mediumText {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
p.largeText {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

my HTML Code:

```
<h3>Small Text</h3>
<p class="smallText">Small text</p>
<h2>Medium Text</h2>
<p class="mediumText">Medium Text</p>
<h1>Large Text </h1>
<p class="largeText">Large Text</p>
```

The Result i am getting:

[image]

I want them to look similar. what styles should I add extra  to make my P tag texts look like H tag texts?

Comment: Please show what you have done so far. Specifically in relation to "accordingly to the content nearby, the size of these P tags changes" . It is easy to debug your code when we can see your code.

Comment: @JonP I have editted my post

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading correctly, you just want to style `<p>` tag as `<h1>`, `<h2>` etc. tags.

The default styles of the heading tags are slightly heavier and bigger.

This is styled as an `<h2>` heading.

```css
p {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

From this link https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp you could see `<h1>` to `<h6>` tag default styles.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I'm going to throw a big guess, don't use `em` this unit is **relative** to its parent size. instead use `rem` or `px` which are **absolute**.

I'll give an exampe here

```css
.first-div {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.second-div{
  font-size: 18px;
}

p {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
  <p>First div</p>
</div>

<div class="second-div">
  <p>Second div</p>
</div>
```

so if you notice `p` will always have `font-size: 2em` but the `em` is relative to the parent element font-size, thus for the `first-div` 2em will equate to 72px while in `second-div` 2em will equate to 36px

I hope this help you to resolve your problems there ;)

Answer (score 1):

Crucially you have missed `font-weight:bold`.

The top tip for this is to use the developer tools in the browser of your choice to inspect the `h` elements and get the styles applied there.

The margins are also different, but you can use the tip above to adjust those as needed.

```css
p.smallText {
    font-size: 1.17em;
    font-weight:bold;
}
p.mediumText {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
}
p.largeText {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<h3>Small Text</h3>
<p class="smallText">Small text</p>
<h2>Medium Text</h2>
<p class="mediumText">Medium Text</p>
<h1>Large Text </h1>
<p class="largeText">Large Text</p>
```

You could also use a html reset for the `h` tags and set your custom `p` styles at the same time.

Something like:

```css
h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3, h4, .h4
{
  font-weight:bold;
}

h5, .h5, h6, .h6
{
  font-weight:normal;  
}


h1, .h1 {
  font-size: 2.15em;
}

h2, .h2 {
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3, .h3 {
  font-size: 1.17em;
}
```

```html
<h3>Small Text</h3>
<p class="h3">Small Text</p>
<h2>Medium Text</h2>
<p class="h2">Medium Text</p>
<h1>Large Text </h1>
<p class="h1">Large Text</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a class to p tag and write css to that class. it should look like below.

```
<p class="custom-p">Text</p>

.custom-p {                       
  font-size:20px;
 }
```

Comment: You should clarify why this is a good answer. for starter, you can say the problem is related to using `em` and that he should instead use `px`